# Polarplot: different colors for the two list to be plotted

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpmath import *
import random

def graphMesure(listeAlpha,listeBeta):
    # Compute areas and colors
    r = np.asarray([1]*len(listeAlpha)+[0.5]*len(listeBeta))
    colors = np.asarray([0.005]*len(listeAlpha)+[0.2]*len(listeBeta))
    area = 200*r**2

    fig = plt.figure()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
    ax.set_ylim([0,1.25])
    c = ax.scatter(listeAlpha+listeBeta, r, c=colors, s=area, cmap='hsv', alpha=1)

graphMesure([0.5,0.2,0.3],[0.7,0.8,0.2])
```

All the color on my polarplot are the same. I thought that specifying float number for colors like I did would make them of different colors.

How can I for example have the first list given in parameter be plotted as blue and the second one as red ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create [valid colors](https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#module-matplotlib.colors).

Your `colors` looks like this `[0.005 0.005 0.005 0.2   0.2   0.2  ]`.

For example:

```
colors = np.asarray(['r'] * len(listeAlpha) + ['b'] * len(listeBeta))
```

creates `colors` with `['r' 'r' 'r' 'b' 'b' 'b']` and gives blue and red dots in your plot:

[image]